# Chart.js TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data')

Tags: javascript, mysql, chart.js

I'm trying to make a chart which is shown on a website.
My Goal is to have two datasets in one chart and update them with the data from a databank every 10 seconds automatically.

I have done it a few times now but only with one dataset (it worked everytime).
In the browser it says: "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data')" and that the error is related to the line:`myChart.data.datasets[1].data =  currentValue;`

```
const ctx3 = document.getElementById('verteilerboxchart');
var displayVoltage = document.getElementById('displayVoltageVerteilerbox');
var displayCurrent = document.getElementById('displayCurrentVerteilerbox');
var myChart;

/*function refreshData(){ */

async function loadData() {
  try {
      const response = await fetch('verteilerboxDb_into_website.php'); 
      const data = await response.json();
      
      console.log('Daten aus der PHP-Datei: ',data);
      
      const voltageValue = [];
      const time = [];
      const ID = [];
       const currentValue = [];
    
      
      data.forEach(rowData => {
          voltageValue.push(parseFloat(rowData.Spannung));
            currentValue.push(parseFloat(rowData.Strom));
              time.push(rowData.zeitstempel);  
                ID.push(rowData.ID);
      })
      
     
      
      var lengthIdArray = ID.length;
      var VoltageAtMoment = voltageValue[lengthIdArray - 1];
    
      
      if(displayVoltage){
        displayVoltage.textContent = VoltageAtMoment;
        } else {
            console.error("displayVoltageVerteilerbox not found!")
          }
          
      var CurrentAtMoment = currentValue[lengthIdArray - 1];
      if(displayCurrent){
        displayCurrent.textContent = CurrentAtMoment;
        } else {
            console.error("displayVoltageVerteilerbox not found!")
          }
      
      
myChart = new Chart(ctx3, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: time,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Verteilerboxspannung in V',
      data: voltageValue,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
      
    },{
      label: 'Verteilerboxstrom in A',
      data: currentValue,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',}]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks:{
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
        }
      },

      x: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks:{
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
        }
      }
    },
plugins:{
  legend: {
    labels: {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' // Farbe des Labelnamens
    }
}
}

  }
});

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Fehler beim Laden der Daten: ', error);

}
}
loadData();


async function updateChartData(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch('verteilerboxDb_into_website.php'); 
      const data = await response.json();
      
      console.log('Daten aus der PHP-Datei: ',data);
      
      const voltageValue = [];
      const currentValue = [];
      const time = [];
      const ID = [];
    
      
      data.forEach(rowData => {
        voltageValue.push(parseFloat(rowData.Spannung));
          currentValue.push(parseFloat(rowData.Strom));
            time.push(rowData.zeitstempel);  
              ID.push(rowData.ID);
      })
      
     
      
      var lengthIdArray = ID.length;
      var VoltageAtMoment = voltageValue[lengthIdArray - 1];
      var CurrentAtMoment = currentValue[lengthIdArray - 1];
      
      if(displayVoltage){
        displayVoltage.textContent = VoltageAtMoment;
        } else {
            console.error("displayVoltageVerteilerbox not found!")
          }
          
          
          
          
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data =  voltageValue;
        myChart.data.datasets[1].data =  currentValue;

    myChart.update();
    } catch(error) {
    console.error('Fehler beim updaten der Daten', error);
    }
    
}
var UpdateInterval = setInterval(updateChartData, 10000);
```

I printed the currentValue[] from the updateChartData-function in the terminal and it gives me the correct data.

I tried only myChart.data.datasets[0].data =  voltageValue; which worked.
I tried only myChart.data.datasets[1].data =  currentValue; which didn't worked.
Tried both at the same time (as seen above) which didn't worked.

Also I did a console.log("myChart.data.datasets[1].data: ", myChart.data.datasets[1].data) which gave me the correct data from the array.

Please help me :(

Here is a jsfiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/vcqfrsnp/

Comment: please share this jsfiddle with the issue replicate to proceed further!  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcqfrsnp/)

Comment: How is this problem related to MySQL? You haven't shared any such code

Comment: @Nico Haase The database which is used to store the data is a MySQL database. I thought someone with MySQL-experience maybe had the same error.

Comment: Is this really a MySQL problem? Would it work better if you generated the JS code any other way?

Comment: I dont know. It works when I only update one dataset. I think it isn't a problem with MySQL. @NicoHaase